# DeviceIoControl returns error 24

Tags: c++, memory, kernel, driver, deviceiocontrol

I am trying to run a custom made kernel mode driver on a windows 7(64 bit) machine. The driver service was started but the IO control request returns error.

DeviceIoControl(hDevice, OPEN_PHYSICAL_MEMORY, NULL, 0, ph, sizeof(HANDLE), cb, NULL)

and  #define OPEN_PHYSICAL_MEMORY __CTL_CODE(0x8124, 0x801, 0, FILE_READ_DATA ).

The getlasterror() returns error code 24.

ERROR_BAD_LENGTH

```
24 (0x18)

The program issued a command but the command length is incorrect.
```

The function runs perfectly in 32 bit OS. Please help me to solve this error.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

sizeof(HANDLE) - this is 4 byte for 32bit app, but from 64bit driver view - this is 8 byte. here and error